# Why isn't 'params' cleared between requests in a controller spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, parameters, controller

I have the following code:

```
let(:params) do
  {
    customer: {
      email: 'testing@mailinator.com',
      confirmation_number: "12345"
    }
  }
end

it 'does something' do
  post :create, params: params
  get :show, params: { cache_key: 1 }
  expect(something).to be_truthy
end
```

The `show` action receives `:params` without `:customer` key, but when this spec runs, `params` has what was sent in the `post` request plus what was sent in the `get` request.

Why does this happen and how can I make Rspec mimic a real behavior between requests (regarding what's inside of `params`)?

Comment: I think 'params' is a reserved keyword at times - have you tried with a different variable name?

Comment: I have, the behavior is the same.

Comment: Maybe try explicitly setting it to nil between your post and your get request?

Comment: I feel they have to be written as two separate tests...

Comment: I know that would workaround it, but my point is that I think I shouldn't have to.
How can I test controllers correctly if the params get appended in a non realistic way. The real question is why does this (counter-intuitive) thing happens. And then if there is a configuration in rspec (since I would like to have that in all my controller tests and not having to hand patch every one of them).

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Are you saying that no controller test should have 2 different requests?

Comment: Controller specs - A controller spec is an RSpec wrapper for a Rails functional test. It allows you to simulate a single http request in each example, and then specify expected outcomes

Request specs - Request specs provide a thin wrapper around Rails' integration tests, and are designed to drive behavior through the full stack, including routing (provided by Rails) and without stubbing (that's up to you).

So if you want to test API controllers I would recommend to use Controller specs as you are testing single requests.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, I kind of felt that I just had to undestand why the rspec people made it like this. You can make that the actual answer. Thanks @VamsiKrishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller specs** - A controller spec is an RSpec wrapper for a Rails functional test. It allows you to simulate a single http request in each example, and then specify expected outcomes

**Request specs** - Request specs provide a thin wrapper around Rails' integration tests, and are designed to drive behavior through the full stack, including routing (provided by Rails) and without stubbing (that's up to you).

So if you want to test API controllers I would recommend to use Controller specs as you are testing single requests.

Comment: TL;DR: this specs are designed to work with only one request.